# How do I get my components to return a serialization of themselves?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still learning React and Javascript so thank you for your patience.

I am trying to serialize my form data so I can send it to a Ruby on Rails back end for processing. I am just using vanilla React with no additional depedencies like Flux, Redux, etc.

It seems like my child components are not returning anything and I am not quite sure why.

I have tried:

- exposing values through the use of refs (but failed and read that it isn't really a good idea to do that anyway)
- exposing a parent method within my child components to gather information about each individual component (what you will see in my jsfiddle).
- updating component states through onChange methods and trying to access the states of each child component

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/morahood/0ptdpfu7/91/

I am clearly missing a key element of React design patterns here. Am I just way off track? How can I get back on track? I would like to eventually be able to serialize the form data in the following format

```
{
   "service_request" : {
      "services" : [
        {
          "service_item" : ["Oil Change", "New Windshield Wipers"],
          "customer" : "Troy",
          "manufacturer" : "Ford",
          "model" : "F150"
        },
        {
          "service_item" : ["Tire Rotation"],
          "customer" : "Dave",
          "manufacturer" : "Hyundai",
          "model" : "Genesis"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

## Components

```
var ServiceForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleFormSubmission }>
        { this.state.serviceItems.map(function(item) {
          return (item);
        })}
        <div className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={ this.addServiceItem }>+ Append New Service Item</div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      serviceItems: [<ServiceItem serializeServiceItem={ this.serializeServiceItem } />]
    });
  },

  handleFormSubmission: function() {
    console.log("form submitted!");
    alert("Serialized Form Data: " +  this.serializeFormData());
  },

  addServiceItem: function(event) {
    var serviceItems = this.state.serviceItems;
    serviceItems.push(<ServiceItem serializeServiceItem={ this.serializeServiceItem } />);

    this.setState({
      serviceItems: serviceItems
    });
  },

  serializeServiceItem: function() {
    var jsonData = {
      "service_item" : this.state.service_items,
      "customer" : this.state.customer,
      "manufacturer" : this.state.manufacturer,
      "model" : this.state.model
    }
    return (jsonData);    
  },

  serializeFormData: function() {
    return( this.state.serviceItems.map(function(item) {
      return (item.serializeServiceItem);
    }));
  }
});

var ServiceItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Service Item </label>
            <select multiple name="service_item" selected={ this.state.service_items } className="form-control">
              <option>Oil Change</option>
              <option>Tire Rotation</option>
              <option>New Wiper Blades</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Customer </label>
            <select name="customer" selected={ this.state.customer } className="form-control">
              <option>Troy</option>
              <option>Dave</option>
              <option>Brandon</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>        

        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Manufacturer </label>
            <div className="input-group">
               <input name="manufacturer" value={ this.state.manufacturer } onChange={ this.setManufacturer } type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Model </label>
            <div className="input-group">
               <input name="model" value={ this.state.model } onChange={ this.setModel } type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return({
      service_items: [],
      customer: "",
      manufacturer: "",
      model: ""
    });
  },

  setModel: function(event) {
    this.setState({ model: event.target.value });
  },

  setManufacturer: function(event) { 
    this.setState({ manufacturer: event.target.value });
  },

  setCustomer: function(event) {
    this.setState({ customer: event.target.selected });
  },

  setServiceItems: function(event) {
    this.setState({ service_items: event.target.selected });
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ServiceForm />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

## Solution

https://jsfiddle.net/morahood/cp569zg6/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "might" be way overcomplicating things here. The DOM element for `<form>` can actually be treated as an array of all the inner `<input>` elements. In other words, if you have:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <form ref="form">
      ...
    </form>
  );
}
```

All your input elements can be accessed by:

```
serialized = {}
for (var i in this.refs.form) {
  var input = this.refs.form[i];
  serialized[input.name] = input.value;
}
```

---

This might not provide you with enough flexibility. A better solution might be to define methods in your component instances that return the input values:

```
var ServiceForm = React.createClass({
  serializeFormData: function() {
    return {
      foo: this.refs.foo.serialize()
    };
  },

  render: function() {
     var foo = this.state.foo;
     return (
       <ServiceItem data={foo} ref="foo" />
     );
  }
});

var ServiceItem = React.createClass({
  serialize: function() {
    return {
      model: this.refs.model.value,
      ...
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    var model = this.props.data.model;
    return (
      <input ref="model" value={model} ... />
    );
  }
});
```

---

If you need multiple service items, you'll probably need to rely on `this.props.children` to access each component instance rather than on `this.refs`:

```
var ServiceContainer = React.createClass({
  collectFormData: function() {
    return this.refs.form.serialize();
  },

  renderServiceItem: function(item, i) {
    return (
      <ServiceItem data={item} key={i} />
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    // Assuming you've moved all your state logic into this ServiceContainer
    var serviceItems = this.state.serviceItems;
    return (
      <ServiceForm ref="form">
        {serviceItems.map(this.renderServiceItem)}
      </ServiceForm>
    );
  }
});

var ServiceForm = React.createClass({
  serialize: function() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(item) {
      return item.serialize();
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
});

var ServiceItem = React.createClass({
  serialize: function() {
    // You can still access your input elements through refs in here
    ...
  },

  render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Note that I'm using [`React.Children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) here rather than simply using `this.props.children` because when there's only a single child, `children` is not an array (see: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html).

Comment: Thank you Wex. I feel like this is getting me closer to my goal. I am trying to implement your second suggestion and finally were able to get some resemblance to a JSON structure being returned. Unfortunately the child components are returning empty. I have updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/morahood/0ptdpfu7/115/. If I have multiple ServiceItems do i need to iterate through each one in the serializeFormData method?

Comment: I added an example of how you could use `this.props.children` to give you access to each `ServiceItem` instead of using `this.refs`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is putting me on the right track and getting me where I need to go. I think I just need to digest this post a little bit more to fully understand what is going on but I feel like this is an extremely helpful and valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use react.rb and reactive-record which will do all this for you out of the box. http://reactrb.org